# Prove that for all positive integers $n$: When $n$ and $n^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they have the same ones digit.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Note:** I have attempted to prove the statement above using mathematical induction, but I am not entirely certain of its correctness. I would appreciate any guidance or feedback on the proof.*

***Proof:***

To prove that for all positive integers $n$, when $n$ and $n^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they have the same ones digit, we can use mathematical induction.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement: "When $n$ and $n^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they have the same ones digit."

**Base Case (n = 1):**
Let's check if $P(1)$ is true.

- $1$ in base $3$ is just $1$.
- $1^3 = 1$ in base $3$ is also just $1$.

The ones digit of $n$ and $n^3$ is the same (both are $1$), so $P(1)$ is true for the base case.

**Inductive Step:**
Assume that $P(k)$ is true for some positive integer $k$, which means when $k$ and $k^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they have the same ones digit. We will prove that $P(k+1)$ is true, which means when $(k+1)$ and $(k+1)^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they also have the same ones digit.

Now, let's consider $(k+1)$ and $(k+1)^3$:

- $(k+1)$ in base $3$ may have a ones digit of $0$, $1$, or $2$. We'll consider each case:

**Case 1: If the ones digit of $(k+1)$ is $0$:**

In this case, $(k+1)$ is divisible by $3$. Therefore, $(k+1)^3$ will also be divisible by $3$, and its ones digit in base $3$ will be $0$.

**Case 2: If the ones digit of $(k+1)$ is $1$:**

In this case, $(k+1)$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$. Therefore, $(k+1)^3$ will leave the same remainder when divided by $3$ (since the cube of a number with a remainder of $1$ is still $1$ when divided by $3$), and its ones digit in base $3$ will be $1$.

**Case 3: If the ones digit of $(k+1)$ is $2$:**

In this case, $(k+1)$ leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$. Therefore, $(k+1)^3$ will leave the same remainder when divided by $3$ (since the cube of a number with a remainder of $2$ is still $2$ when divided by $3$), and its ones digit in base $3$ will be $2$.

In all three cases, the ones digit of $(k+1)$ and $(k+1)^3$ is the same in base $3$.

So, by induction, we have shown that for all positive integers $n$, when $n$ and $n^3$ are expressed in base $3$, they have the same ones digit.

Comment: You never use the inductive hypothesis, and in each case, you just state the conclusion that you want to reach without providing a reason, e.g. *"since the cube of a number with a remainder of $1$  is still $1$ when divided by $3$"*

Comment: Looks ok but there is no real need for induction.

Comment: @SammyBlack enlighten me kindly how to fix if there is an error.

Comment: @coffeemath which other way we can do this?

Comment: $n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what do you mean by this statement?

Comment: I mean that this statement is trivially true (among three consecutive numbers, exactly one is divisible by $3$). This then means that $n^3$ and $n$ differ by a multiple of $3$, hence their unit digits are identical.

Comment: @Ameer786 Instead of induction, just show it for the three cases where k has last digit 0,1,2 when written in base 3. Of course you  need to *prove* that if k has last digit d when written in base 3 so does k^3, for each of d=0,1,2. [you really did not do that in your induction proof either]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction proof is not *wrong*, but since you never use the induction hypothesis, it could be simplified to a direct proof. To prove that $n$ and $n^3$ have the same ones digit in base $3$, simply consider the same three cases:

- The ones digit of $n$ is $0$;
- The ones digit of $n$ is $1$;
- The ones digit of $n$ is $2$.

In each case, you already have an argument that shows that $n^3$ has the same ones digit as $n$ - you're just writing it for $k+1$ instead of $n$.

---

There *is*, however, an interesting inductive argument. Here is how that looks (I will pick back up from the second paragraph of the inductive step in the question):

Now, let's consider $k+1$ and $(k+1)^3$.

Clearly, $k+1$ has the *next* ones digit after $k$'s ones digit: if $k$ ends in $0$, $1$, or $2$, then $k+1$ ends in $1$, $2$, or $0$, respectively.

We can also check that $(k+1)^3$ has the next ones digit after $k^3$'s ones digit, because $$(k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k+1.$$ Adding $3k^2+3k$ does not affect the ones digit, so the only relevant effect is adding $1$.

By the inductive hypothesis, $k$ and $k^3$ have the same ones digit, and we've just proven that both $k+1$ and $(k+1)^3$ advance that digit by exactly one step; therefore they must also have the same ones digit!

*Note that here, in the last paragraph, we did use $P(k)$ to prove $P(k+1)$, which is what makes induction necessary.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be proved directly without induction.

*Hint:* What are the factors of $n^3 - n$ and what does that tell us about divisibility by $3$?

> Since $n^3 - n = (n-1)n(n+1)$, which are $3$ consecutive integers, one of the factors is a multiple of $3$, so $n^3 - n = 3k$ for some integer $k$. So each of $n^3$ and $n$ must have the same remainder upon division by $3$, i.e. the same unit digit in base $3$.

Comment: By the way, this works for any prime $p$: expressed in base $p$, the numbers $n$ and $n^p$ have the same units digit. This is one of many ways to state [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: I appreciate the your way but is my induction proof correct or not?

Comment: No. You never use the induction hypothesis, at least not explicitly.

Comment: That doesn't make the induction proof incorrect - it just makes it silly.

Comment: I guess... I mean, it makes it not an induction proof.